# Memory not be freed on Mac when vector push_back string

Tags: string, macos, memory, vector, objective-c++

Code as below, found that when vector `push_back` string on a Mac demo app, memory not be freed. I thought the stack variable will be freed when out of function scope, am I wrong?  Thanks for any tips.

in `model.h`:

```
#pragma once
namespace NS {
    const uint8_t kModel[8779041] = {4,0,188,250,....};
}
```

in `ViewController.mm`:

```
- (void)start {
    std::vector<std::string> params = {};
    std::string strModel(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(NS::kModel), sizeof(NS:kModel));
    params.push_back(strModel);
}
```

Comment: What is not released? `kModel` is statically allocated, so it will only be released at the end of the program. But both `params` and `strModel` will be destroyed at the end of the `start` function.

Comment: Memory is freed when a string or vector of strings goes out of scope. It is freed in the sense that **your program** can allocate that memory again. It is not necessarily freed in the sense that the operating system can assign that memory to other programs. That kind of freedom only happens when your program exits.

Comment: @john You mean macOS memory mechanism may not free those memory, though we thought they should be freed? Can you show me the official documents about how memory free or release works, I've googled but found nothing.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Unfortunately they won't be freed on macOS. I don't know why

Comment: How are you determining that the memory is supposedly not freed?

Comment: @Smeegol Like I said it depends on what you mean by freed. The memory does get freed to **your program**, it does not get freed to the **operating system**. This is true on Windows and Linux as well as MacOS.

Comment: @pmdj I using Xcode's Debug navigator's Memory dashboard to get the information of memory

Comment: @Smeegol This will only give you overall trends, as it tracks memory mapped into the process. Freeing small amounts of memory will typically not cause any unmapping, only returning it to the allocator's free pool. The memory dashboard is primarily intended for observing memory usage trends at a very high level. It helps you notice things like large memory leaks, and roughly correlating large allocations with specific events in your program.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends on your understanding of the the "free" memory. The behaviour you are observing can be reproduced as simple as with a couple lines of code:

```cpp
void myFunc() {
    const auto *ptr = new uint8_t[8779041]{};
    delete[] ptr;
}
```

Let's run this function and see how the memory consumption graph changes:

```cpp
int main() {
    myFunc(); // 1 MB
    std::cout << "Check point" << std::endl; // 9.4 MB
    return 0;
}
```

If you put one breakpoint right at the line with `myFunc()` invocation and another one at the line with `"Check point"` console output, you will witness how memory consumption for the process jumps by about *8 MB* (for my system and machine configuration Xcode shows sudden jump from *1 MB* to *9.4 MB*). But wait, isn't it supposed to be *1 MB* again after the function, as the allocated memory is freed at the end of the function? Well, not exactly.. The system doesn't regain this memory right away, because it's not that cheap operation to begin with, and if your process requests the same amount memory 1 CPU cycle later, it would be quite a redundant work. Thus, the system usually doesn't bother shrinking memory dedicated to a process either until it's needed for another process, and until it runs out of available resources (it also can be some kind of fixed timer, but overall I would say this is implementation-defined). Another common reason the memory is not freed, is because you often observe it through debug mode, where the memory remains dedicated to the process to track some tricky scenarios (like `NSZombie` objects, which address needs to remain accessible to the process in order to report the use-after-free occasions).

The most important here is that internally, the process can differentiate between "deleted" and "occupied" memory pages, thus it can re-occupy memory which is already deleted. As a result, no matter how many times you call the same function, the memory dedicated to the process remains the same:

```cpp
int main() {
    myFunc(); // 1 MB
    std::cout << "Check point" << std::endl; // 9.4 MB
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
        myFunc();
    }
    std::cout << "Another point" << std::endl; // 9.4 MB
    return 0;
}
```